# Can I apply for a Russian visa from the country Georgia?

Tags: russia, visas, georgia-country, caucasus

I will be in Georgia in the Caucasus in a few months and am considering a side trip to Russia; either via the Black Sea to Sochi or across [the one land border that is apparently open to foreigners](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/289/is-the-border-between-georgia-and-russia-open-to-citizens-of-other-countries).

But considering the recent history and delicate political situation between these countries, is it possible for a foreigner to get a visa to Russia while in Georgia? If not what about Armenia? If not, what other possibilities exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Embassy of Switzerland in Georgia, Russian Federation Interests Section](http://www.georgia.mid.ru/) is issuing the Russian visas in Tbilisi, but not the touristic ones, unfortunately. So you must apply for a visa in Australia.

Answer (score 8):

Everything I've been told about Russian visas (and I'm in Russia now) is that you can ONLY apply for a visa from your country of citizenship, OR your country of residency, if the two are different.  Which was handy for me as a New Zealander living in the UK.

From http://www.visatorussia.com/russianvisa.nsf/FaqNew.html :

"If you apply for a visa not in your own country, a copy of your residence or work permit in the country of your temporary residence may also be required. In this case our operators will inform you about this additional requirement. "

Which would seem to imply that yes, you can from Georgia IF and only IF you are currently working there.

However, I'd suggest contacting visatorussia.com, as they may have some additional tricks.

Comment: Hmm if I have to apply in Australia then definitely no Russia for me this year since I'm already in Korea and flying to Turkey tomorrow )-:

Comment: All you can do is to try to consult the Russian сonsul in country you currently are in. But I think what this can be really a problem.

Comment: Russian consulates can often be quite flexible, though I would recommend finding someone who speaks fluent Russian for such negotiations.

Comment: I can't comment on this point exactly - but I was told I would need to apply for a Syrian visa in my home country (UK) - but managed to get one in Jordan. It's probably worth a try if it's your only option - and if one says no try a different one in another country - nothing to lose. Just be polite to them - they often have the power.

Comment: Have to disagree with that, I did get a Russian tourist visa without any problems in Osaka while only being in Japan as a tourist in June 2015.

Answer (score 5):

As of June 2016, I can confirm that a foreign non-resident can apply and receive a tourist visa to Russia in Tbilisi, Georgia. I've just picked mine up from the consulate.

The process wasn't simple, and the application is long, but it is possible.

There are some additional requirements for Australian citizens, requiring the application to be completed in Russian, and the submission of an "autobiography", also in Russian.

I wrote about the whole process and my experience on my travel blog - [Apply For A Visa To Russia In Tbilisi, Georgia](http://pineappleexplorer.com/2016/06/15/apply-visa-russia-tbilisi-georgia/)