# Is it possible to get a train from Georgia to Moscow?

Tags: russia, driving, georgia-country, caucasus

I am thinking of doing a road trip to Georgia, dumping my car there then travelling to Moscow, to continue on the Trans-Siberian to Beijing. Does anyone know if its possible for me to travel over the border either via coach or train or should I re-think my plans?

Comment: First you should rethink your abuse of Capslock ;)

Comment: Ah, someone is yelling at me...

Answer (score 7):

As I've said in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2069/which-route-did-the-old-tbilisi-rostov-train-route-take-and-is-it-closed-only-for/2072#2072), you can use Baku as connection point, and use train to travel. There is no such problems on the border between [Azerbaijan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azerbaijan) and Russia, and you wouldn't spend much time on this trip.

Another option is to get into the Abkhazia from Georgia ([if you can](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1063/can-i-visit-abkhazia-from-the-republic-of-georgia)), and use the train to the Moscow. But in this case you'll get problems with Georgia officials at the next visit into the Georgia.

Comment: Added variant with the Abkhazia train.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see [in this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/289/is-the-border-between-georgia-and-russia-open-to-citizens-of-other-countries), the biggest problem is probably that the border is sometimes closed for non-citizens. So you have the problem that it is not always possible to enter Russia from Georgia.

As you can see [here](http://www.hansrossel.com/travel-information/georgia-tbilisi/public-transport.htm), there isn't a direct train to Russia anymore. But you could use a coach or the ferry.

Comment: Yes if you're not from Russia, Georgia, or another former CIS country it seems to be very difficult to cross the border from Georgia to Russia, something I would also like to do.