# Visiting both Abkhazia and Georgia

Tags: georgia-country, disputed-territories, caucasus

Reading up about Georgia I found out through the [UK travel advisory](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/georgia/safety-and-security) that it's illegal under Georgian law to travel to Abkhazia from Georgia.

Does this restriction extend to all travel to Abkhazia, that is, would someone not be able to visit Georgia anymore because of a past trip to Abkhazia, regardless of how they got there ?

Is the situation reciprocal, would Abkhazia turn you back if they know you've been to Georgia ?

*Note: This is different from [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1063/is-it-possible-to-visit-abkhazia-by-land-from-georgia) which seeks to enter from Georgia by land and predates a [legal amendment](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85#.D0.98.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.8F.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B0)*

Comment: The travel advise says that it is illegal to enter Georgia from Abkhazia since there is no official border control there. Why do you assume that previous travel to Abkhazia could prevent your from legally entering Georgia later (through an official border checkpoint)?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo because the initial law was a criminal offence and carried a fine, and because other disputes also result in such exclusions (think Armenia/Azerbaijan/Turkey, Israel/Arab countries)

Comment: I've heard that it's not nearly as strongly enforced as it was around 2008-10, and I know people who've crossed that way, but that was a few years ago, don't know what it's like now. Plenty of families live either side of the border, it's a geopolitical standoff but it's not an Israel-Palestine type situation. Here's a recent-ish first person account which is similar to how my friends told it - http://www.meganstarr.com/all-you-need-to-know-about-traveling-to-abkhazia/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is absolutely untrue.

The ONLY legal way to enter occupied territories is to enter Georgia first through official checkpoint, and then visit Abkhazia or, God forbid, South Ossetia through, again, official Georgian temporary checkpoint. My Czech friend did this last year and had no problems whatsoever.

But if you have Abkhazian stamp from Psou or any of their sea checkpoints, you will have trouble with Georgian border guards and police whenever you enter Georgia from ANY, even official checkpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that you'd have problems, provided you don't do anything suspicious. I've lived in Georgia all my life and have yet to hear of anyone, especially a tourist, being caught for that. Having said that, you should definitely be on your guard in Abkhazia. Although a place of untold beauty and definitely worth a visit, it's a militarized territory with non-authorized armed mercenaries freely roaming.