# How feasible is it to travel from Singapore all the way to London only by Train

Tags: trains, london, russia, singapore

I am wondering how feasible (apart from the economic point of view) it is to travel from Singapore to London by train and having to change to other means of transport as minimum as possible.

As far as I know, these are the possible itinerary

1. Board the Orient & Express Train from Singapore to Bangkok
2. Bangkok to Vietnam (Hanoi or Ho Chi Min City) ??? is any direct rain service connecting these two cities?
3. From Hanoi (Vietnam) all the way to Beijing (China) requires a change at Dong Dang station.
4. Once in China, there are many possibilities to go to Europe by Train using the famous Transsiberian.
5. From Moscow, options are abundant. One could go directly to London or make a few stopover in German, Paris or other European city.

How feasible is it to travel by train from Singapore to London by train (at least in terms of safety and reliability).

Comment: Ok, it's a great title, but you've asked MANY detailed questions in there.  Visas/permits is a whole issue for each country on its own!  I'd really consider simplifying - say into just "is it possible" first, then the other questions.  Also realise that several of your subquestions are subjective - what do you mean by "how reliable" is a train? If you're after timeliness, or safety, or something, you'll need to specify.

Comment: This trip is very feasible. See here: http://www.seat61.com/Malaysia.htm#to Singapore overland

Comment: About visas, a related question is: [What is the best way to obtain visas for the Trans-Siberian/Trans-Mongolian Railway?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11/241).

Comment: Why is this flagged as a duplicate?  The other question is about traveling by any means over land, this is specifically about train travel -- the answers will not be the same.

Comment: It could be a duplicate if this one is a subset of that one, meaning if the other one specifically does cover doing it solely by train. If it doesn't cover it then I'd vote to reopen.

Comment: Since the answers there focus on train travel, this seems appropriate.