# How to list Trans-Siberian as a hotel on a Russian visa application

Tags: visas, russia, trans-siberian

I'm filling out my visa application and my understanding is that I should ensure the list of hotels on my application, so that it matches what's on my tourist invitation. I got Moscow and Irkutsk filled out fine, and `TRANSSIB` showed up on the list of cities, so I entered that, but the invitation also includes the train as a "hotel". Anyone know how I should enter it, since both address and phone number are mandatory fields that aren't going to exist (the invitation doesn't give anything to enter for those fields either)? I'm specifically referring to the `Do you plan to stay anywhere (hotel, individual) during your stay in Russia?` section, which then asks for the name, address, and phone number of each.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11/19

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The other question is "how to get a visa",  and all the answers are "use an agency"; this one is "I'm getting my own visa, how do I fill out the application?"

Comment: Are you booking the rail tickets through an agency? You may be able to use that company's address and phone. Will the app let you submit without TRANSSIB, as the visa authorities likely understand that it indicates your transportation portion.

Comment: I managed to get a hold of the agency that issued my tourist invitation. They said to leave the Trans-Sib off the hotels section entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured I'd answer my own question in case anyone else has this issue. As I mentioned in a comment, the agency that issued my invitation said to leave off the Trans-Sib from the hotels section. I did include it as a "city" to visit, however. I just got my passport back today with the visa in it, so I can confirm that is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

OP comment provided the answer:

> I managed to get ahold of the agency that issued my tourist invitation. They said to leave the Trans-Sib off the hotels section entirely.