# Are Australian 35x45mm passport photos accepted for Chinese visas?

Tags: visas, china, australian-citizens, photography

The Chinese embassy in Australia publishes a [very strict set of guidelines](http://au.china-embassy.org/eng/ls/vfc/t1417900.htm) regarding acceptable passport photos.  They vary subtly but distinctly from the rules for [regular passport photos](https://www.passports.gov.au/passports-explained/how-apply/passport-photo-guidelines) in Australia: for example, the photo must be 33x48mm (vs min. 35x45mm), height of head must be 28-33mm (vs 32-36 mm), etc.

In practice, are regular 35x45mm Australian passport photos accepted?  Or do I really need to go get a separate set just for this?

Comment: As one data point I've used cheap-o Costco passport photos at the Toronto one a couple of times without problems.

Comment: don't be fooled by the title of the dupe - question, answers, comments are all primarily about how close you have to be to the guidelines.

Comment: @KateGregory My question is a very specific subset though: are 45x35mm photos close enough or not?